# How to insert an icon, while compiling a code?

Tags: .net, compilation, icons

How to compile my code (C#) by dotnet.exe such that the compiled code has an icon?

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are talking about a Console Application or a Windows Application.

Go to the Menu bar, select **Project** > **YourProjectName Properties**. Go to the **Aplication** tab and select "**Icon and manifest**",then "**Browse...**" and select your icon in **.ico extension**.

Best regards. :)

Comment: This method works in Visual Studio. But I am working with dotnet.exe, so any task should be written in command line of CMD.